# Java method running very slowly on first run only (Android)

Tags: java, android, performance

I have found that my method called checkForErrors takes around 80x longer to run on the first execution only, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
D/guess: adhl
D/checkerror: checking for errors took 4760743ns // first run
D/validity: checking guess validity took 7141114ns
D/guess: agkl
D/checkerror: checking for errors took 61035ns // every other run takes around this long
D/validity: checking guess validity took 732422ns
```

I have looked through the code and I don't see anything that would take longer on the first run only so I'm stumped.

Button on click listener:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Guess = guess_txt.getText().toString();
            Log.d("guess", Guess);
            if(checkGuessValidity(Guess)){ // <--
                submitValidGuess(Guess);
                int bulls = game.getBullsAndHits()[0];
                int hits = game.getBullsAndHits()[1];
                if(!game.gameWon) //if game is not won, submit the guess with bulls and hits
                    guessSubmittedListener.guessSubmitted(Guess, bulls, hits);
                else //if game is won, call gameWon() method
                    gameEnd();
            }
            if((game.getCurrentTry() > game.getMaxTries()) && (!Guess.equals(game.getHiddenWord()))) gameEnd(); //if user is out of tries, call gameLost method

            triesLeft.setText("Tries Left: " + (game.getMaxTries() - game.getCurrentTry() + 1)); //update tries left on main fragment
            guess_txt.setText("");
        }
    });
```

checkGuessValidity:

```
public boolean checkGuessValidity(String Guess){
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    ErrorList Status = checkForErrors(Guess); // <--
    long end2 = System.nanoTime();

    Log.d("checkerror", "checking for errors took " + (end2 - start2) + "ns");
    . . . more code . . .
```

checkForErrors:

```
public ErrorList checkForErrors(String Guess){
    if(Guess.length() != game.getHiddenWordLength()) return ErrorList.Wrong_Length;
    else if(!isValidInput(Guess)) return ErrorList.Invalid_Characters;
    else if(!isIsogram(Guess)) return ErrorList.Not_Isogram;
    else if(!isLowercase(Guess)) return ErrorList.Not_Lowercase;
    else return ErrorList.OK;
}
```

isValidInput, isIsogram and isLowercase:

```
public boolean isIsogram(String Guess){
    Map<Character, Boolean> map = new HashMap();

    for(int i = 0; i < Guess.length(); i++){
        if(map.get(Guess.charAt(i)) == null) //if the value for the key (character) is null (has not been changed since map initialization)
            map.put(Guess.charAt(i), true); //then set it to true (indicating that it has been seen)
        else { //else (if the value at the character HAS been changed since initialization, ie. it has been seen)
            Log.d("Character repeated", "" + Guess.charAt(i));
            return false; //return false
        }
    }
    return true; //if loop completes no duplicates were found and guess is an isogram
}

public boolean isLowercase(String Guess){
    if(Guess.equals(Guess.toLowerCase())) return true;
    else return false;
}

public boolean isValidInput(String Guess){
    char[] chars = Guess.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        if(!isLatinLetter(chars[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isLatinLetter(char c) {
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}
```

It doesn't seem like any of the methods should be impacted by when they are run, so I don't know why it takes extra long on the first execution. I'm still a beginner to programming so please excuse any poor formatting or horribly optimized code :p .

edit: CPU usage graph: https://prnt.sc/ftjokq

Comment: Hashmap has a containsKey method. Not sure if that's better than a null check

Comment: Has running through a profiler unveiled any secrets?

Comment: Also, have you ran this purely in Java, not Android where the background operations could be doing whatever?

Comment: @cricket_007 in this case, you can simply put and check if the return value is non-null to indicate a duplicate. Or use a Set, and check for `add` returning false.

Comment: Perhaps the Just in Time compiler needs some time to kick off: https://dzone.com/articles/just-time-compiler-jit-hotspot